# Having a hard time proving a limit does not exist (in two variables)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find whether or not the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y^2}{x^5+y^3},$$ $$x^5+y^3\neq0$$

exists. According to my teacher the limit is not supposed to exist, and here comes the part where I am stuck.

I did try to use polar coordinates
$$x=rcos(\theta)$$
$$y=rsin(\theta)$$
and it got me to
$$\frac{x^3y^2}{x^5+y^3}=\frac{r^3cos^3(\theta)r^2sin^2(\theta)}{r^5cos^5(\theta)+r^3sin^3(\theta)}=\frac{r^2cos^3(\theta)sin^2(\theta)}{r^2cos^5(\theta)+sin^3(\theta)}$$

How can I proceed from here to prove that the limit **does not exist** ? Every time I try to substitute something it always gives me the same answer, which is that if the limit exists, it is equal to $0$.

I link to a handwritten solution to the problem below that I can't seem to understand, so if anyone is willing to explain what my teacher is actually doing I would appreciate it greatly!

(There are a few words in swedish that I don't think you need to translate to be able to understand the actual solution)

[Handwritten solution from my teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNAp0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue here is to approach on a path very close to $x^5+y^3=0$. Your teacher suggests noticing that you can parametrize this curve by
$$x=t^{1/5}, y=-t^{1/3}.$$
A nearby path is obtained by multiplying $y$ by $(1+\epsilon(t))^{1/3}$, where $\epsilon(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. Taking $\epsilon(t)=t$ shouldn't be too difficult. What happens, then, to $f(x,y)$?

We have $$f(t^{1/5},-t^{1/3}(1+t)^{1/3}) = \frac{t^{3/5}t^{2/3}(1+t)^{2/3}}{t-t(1+t)} = \frac{t^{19/15}(1+t)^{2/3}}{-t^2} = -\frac{(1+t)^{2/3}}{t^{11/15}},$$
and the absolute value of this goes to $\infty$.

Comment: By the way if we assume $x,y>0$ then the limit is $0$ as for example by AM-GM $$x^5+y^3\geq 2\frac{x^3 y^2}{\sqrt{xy}}$$ i.e. $$\frac{x^3y^2}{x^5+y^3}\le \frac{x^3y^2}{2\frac{x^3 y^2}{\sqrt{xy}}}=\frac{\sqrt{xy}}2\to0$$

Comment: Thank you Ted for the explanation. I missed the lecture where my teacher intended to show us how this can be done. I think I do understand what you are saying now.

So what **if** $\epsilon(t)$ could have been canceled in both the numerator and denominator, making the function $f(x,y)$ not dependant on $\epsilon(t)$. **If** the function $f(x,y)$ then tends to $0$, could you then conclude that the limit is in fact $0$ ? (when $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$)

Comment: Well, no, that wouldn't suffice. To prove the limit *does* exist, you can never just check along one (or even infinitely many) path(s). This technique only works to show the limit does *not* exist. To prove the limit *is* $0$, you must actually show that *for all* $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $(0,0)$ we have $|f(x,y)|$ is as small as desired.

Comment: Right, okay. So after trying many different paths that all give the same answer $L$ I should move on to try to actaully prove that the limit is $L$ using the $\epsilon-\delta-definition$ for example?

Comment: Yes. This was an exceedingly tricky problem. The fact that that the denominator vanishes on a curve tips you off that you need a different approach. Often there are simple bounds you can use to make the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ procedure work. ... Here's another similar problem (which I put in my own textbook): $f(x,y) = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}$, for $x\ne y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! This clears things up for me and I will try to solve the problem from your textbook !